# How do I reset a .NET Windows Forms TextBox BackColor property?

Tags: .net, winforms, controls, colors

The default behavior of property `BackColor` of a `TextBox` is as follows: when enabled, it is `White` (`SystemColors.Window`), when disabled it is Gray (not sure what SystemColor this is).

If I change the `BackColor` property, the same color is used for both Enabled and Disabled.  How do I reset the `BackColor` property (after it has been changed previously) so that the behavior reverts to the default?

I have tried setting it back to `SystemColors.Window`, but then the box stays white when disabled.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you mean in the designer, you can just click into the BackColor property and delete whatever is in there and then press enter. This will reset the property back to its default value.

If you mean in code, you can set the BackColor property to [Color.Empty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.empty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and this will have the same effect.

Answer (score 7):

```
TextBox.ResetBackColor()
```

It doesn't pop up in [IntelliSense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliSense) for some reason, but it's there and it compiles.

Comment: I would probably avoid this, as the "Reset[PropertyName]" functions are a part of the serialization framework. Unless there's a compelling reason, I would avoid using functions that are intentionally excluded from Intellisense.

Comment: +1 for this, I went with @ascalonx's solution though for the reason @Adam Robinson mentioned (At least your solution worked, not sure what drugs Adam is on) ;)

Comment: @Alex Ruse,  This compiled for me, too (also didn't show in Intellisense), but didn't actually work at runtime - the backcolor stayed the color that it was set to elsewhere in the program.

Answer (score 3):

`SystemColors.Window` is (usually) white. Use `SystemColors.Control`.

You could, of course, cache the color in use when you set it to your own, then use that to reset it. In the end, though, either approach will work.

Comment: Caching the color is always a good idea :) so that you can return it to it's previous state. Although its a difficult solution when your say, rotating between 5 or 6 colors.

Answer (score 1):

In case there is no way to reset the control so it will return to automatically changing its background color when enabled/disabled I would recommend using the `UIElement.IsEnabledChanged` event to set your desired enabled/disabled 
background colors. I hope this is helpful!

Comment: I think your answer may be talking about when using WPF.  His question is directed at winforms (based on the tags)

Comment: +1 Thanks Adam, that's pretty much what I was doing, I went with another solution posted here as it will most likely work on non-standard color schemes.